# How can iterator through vectors of nodes and check Eulerian circuit?

Tags: c++, graph

How can i Iterator though vectors of nodes and check if it goes through the edge only once? (Eulerian circuit). How can i also print the combination if it is an Eulerian circuit? Here what i have tried but it keep giving me "no matching function to call DFSUtil".

```
#inlucde <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

unsigned int c = 0;
class node
{
public:
    string a;
    vector<node> connect;
    node(string b)
    {
        a = b;
        c++;
    }
     bool isEulerCircuit();
     bool isConnected();
     void DFSUtil(node &a,bool visited[]);
    void add_connect(node &n)
    {
        connect.push_back(n);
    }


};
void node::DFSUtil(node &a,bool visited[])
{
    visited[c] = true;
    vector<node>::iterator i;
    for(i = connect.begin(); i != connect.end(); i++)
    {
        node s = *i;
        if(!visited[c])
        {
            DFSUtil(*i,visited[c]);
        }
    }
 }

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    node A("A"),B("B"), C("C");
    vector<node> AllNodes;
    AllNodes.push_back(A);
    AllNodes.push_back(B);
    AllNodes.push_back(C);

    A.add_connect(B);
    B.add_connect(C);
}
```

Comment: You should rename the topic to "What does the compiler error "No matching function to call...." mean?" and then post the entire error message. Your question and the question in the topic do not match. Additionally, the question in the topic is too general. What you really want is for someone to correct your compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
DFSUtil(*i,visited[c]);
```

makes a call with params Node, and bool, assuming, "c" is actually defined somewhere. I don't see its definition in your listing. Please see "minimal compilable example"

However, you have defined a method that takes a reference to a node and an array of bools:

```
void node::DFSUtil(node &a,bool visited[])
```

I imagine the compiler is complaining that your call with those params doesn't match any method or function that it can find.

Additional errors your listing results with:

```
main.cpp(39): error C2065: 'c': undeclared identifier
main.cpp(41): error C2065: 'connection': undeclared identifier
main.cpp(41): error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
main.cpp(41): note: type is 'unknown-type'
main.cpp(41): error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union
main.cpp(41): note: type is 'unknown-type'
main.cpp(44): error C2065: 'c': undeclared identifier
main.cpp(46): error C2065: 'c': undeclared identifier
main.cpp(46): error C2660: 'node::DFSUtil': function does not take 1 arguments
```

Your listing also has a slew of other problems like making a copy of node every time you create a connection.

Rather than getting someone else to write software for you here. Try to ask questions that narrow down one aspect of what you are having problems with. Test your solution one method at a time, rather than "the whole thing doesn't work, who can fix it?"

Comment: Sorry :/ I've been trying to understand vector graphing but i can't seem to  iterate through the vector